# Regex to check if any latin letter except specific ones is present in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My task is to check if string of an arbitrary length contains any latin letter except specific ones (in my case letters that match roman numerals (I,V,X,L,C) are not allowed)

So if no latin letter is present - the string is invalid, if specific character (mentioned above) is present - the string is invalid. Otherwise the string is valid.

Could someone help me to come up with proper regex for that condition?

Examples:

`123` - invalid

`123 aAA` - valid

`ABD` - valid

`AAa ddDD zzZz` - valid

`AXXXA` - invalid

`IV abc` - invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be it. First part `(?=.*[a-z])` checks for latin letters, and `[^XLVCI]` mathes anything besides these characters.

```js
let string1 = '123'
let string2 = '123 aAA'
let string3 = 'ABD'
let string4 = 'AAa ddDD zzZz'
let string5 = 'AXXXA'
let string6 = 'IV abc'

let regex = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^XLVCI]+$/

let result = string1.match(regex)

console.log(string1.match(regex))
console.log(string2.match(regex))
console.log(string3.match(regex))
console.log(string4.match(regex))
console.log(string5.match(regex))
console.log(string6.match(regex))
```

Comment: Using RegEx101.com this does not appear to match the samples given in the question...

Comment: I added now all of them, test it. Match returns null if it's invalid, if it's valid it returns the string

Comment: @nedoder outstanding! Could you please explain how positive lookahead works in that case? Because most examples shows when lookahead goes after some symbol

Comment: Positive look ahead assertion means that there is at least one symbol that is a-ZA-Z to right from the point. If it finds only digits (not at least one letter), it fails. Does it make it any clearer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard RegEx requirement, build a character class of all the characters you want to match.  From your question this RegEx should do it for you: `/^[^CDILMXV]*(?:[ABE-JKN-UWY-Z])+[^CDILMXV]*$/i`

> **Note:** I am allowing for more roman numerals than you had in your post, if that.s not what you need adjust accordingly.

The RegEx must have at least one allowed latin character (the middle part `(?:[ABE-JKN-UWY-Z])+` and there must be no disallowed latin characters before or after the middle match (the `[^CDILMXV]*` at the start and end)

This should match all of your inputs.